# Can I search memory for a specific object structure?

Tags: c#, memory

Last night I took CheatEngine for a ride, and I found a structure in the game i currently play. The game has 4 characters, each with "health" and "mana", both of these are 4 bytes (int). Is there a way I can scan the application to find the first occurrence?

What I found was that health of player 1 was located at 2DC2E72C, and I'm going to short it to "72C" since the other players health comes very exact after that.

- Player 1 health: 72C
- Player 2 health: 81C
- Player 3 health: 90C
- Player 4 health: 9FC

After some handywork with my trusted microsoft calculator, I found that it is 240 bytes between each players health. Players mana is 4 bytes, placed *right after* health, so the structure is:

- 000 Player 1 health
- 004 Player 1 mana
- 240 Player 2 health
- 244 Player 2 mana
- and so on.

So my question is, could I search for this pattern in the applications memory? The pattern would be something along the line of: 2x4 bytes, 240 bytes, 2x4 bytes, 240 bytes....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text file containing the memory contents you could use regular expressions to search for the pattern you want. Boost has a good library for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there won't be a `managed` way to do that.

However, CheatEngine is an open source program, that does the same

http://www.cheatengine.org/

Maybe you could check out the source code and figure out which API calls you need to achive the same with C#

Update: I see, you already mentioned CheatEngine, overlooked it the first time.
I found this article on CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15680/How-to-write-a-Memory-Scanner-using-C

Looks simple

Answer (score 0):

There was a cheat program back in the day called FreeCheese if I remember correctly. The way it worked was something like this :

1. Take search value from user input
2. Scan game's process memory for any values that match users input and
   store found addresses
3. Ask user to change the value ingame and take
   new value as input
4. Rescan addresses from step 2 and discard those that don't match the new value
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until an address (number of addresses) is found  that always reflect the changes specified by the user
6. Ask the user for a new value and write that value to the addresses found

Step 6 is tricky since you will need to do type / size checks to make sure you can actually apply the new value.

Happy cheating :)